# How to scale amplitude of polar plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, polar-coordinates

I have a matrix of data. I used the [`polarplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html) command in MATLAB to plot this matrix with respect to theta.

The data oscillates between 3999.20 and 4001.52 As you can see in the following plot, the order of magnitude of oscillation of data is too small to see.

How can I modify my polar plot to see small oscillations?

My code is as below:

```
yf=[%750 data point]
theta = 0:4*pi/749:4*pi;
rho = yf
pax = polaraxes;
polarplot(theta,rho)
pax.ThetaDir = 'counterclockwise';
pax.ThetaZeroLocation='right'
pax.ThetaColor='r'
pax.ThetaTick=[0 30 60 90 120 150 180 210 240 270 300 330 ];
pax.RDir='normal';
pax.RTick=[3999.34 3999.67 4000 4000.33 4000.66 4000.99 4001.33 ]
pax.FontSize = 12;
```

### Desired output:

[image: expected plot]

### Actual output

[image: unwanted result.]

### 2-axis plot

[image: picture of simple plot of the matrix of data]

Comment: You can set the [r limits](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rlim.html) for the plot, if all you're looking for is visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give an example of setting the [r limits](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html) as suggested by @beaker

The following code uses the same data with using `rlim` to set manual limits in the second example. This scales the polar axis so that it only plots values between [3999,4000], exaggerating the scale of the oscillation.

```
theta = 0:0.01:2*pi;
rho = sin(2*theta).*cos(2*theta) + 3999 %To approximate your data

figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
polarplot(theta,rho)
title('Automatic r-limits')

subplot(1,2,2)
polarplot(theta,rho)
rlim([3999, 4000])
title('rlim([3999, 4000])')
```

[image: Figure comparing r limits]

Comment: hi Cecilia,
I don't know I can ever thank you. your solution worked out. it seems all my Christmases have come at once. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe, where you subtract the mean of the data and scale the amplitude by a factor of 10?

```
yf=[%750 data point]
amp = yf - mean(yf);
amp = amp*10; % choose whatever scaling factor works for you
theta = 0:4*pi/749:4*pi;
rho = mean(yf) + amp;
```

Without the actual data, it's difficult to say what this will look like, but the general principle should work.